# Separating voice over from background music

Tags: sound-editing

If I have:

1. audio file someone has created by placing a monologue/speech over background music
2. an audio file of the exact background music which was used above

is there any way to "subtract" the background music (2) out of file (1) to be left with only the monologue/speech?

I found [this thread](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/12427/removing-background-location-music-from-documentary-dialogue?newreg=25439a51532f4f0c) which is similar, but a more difficult problem. It was also asked over 10 years ago, so I hope it's okay that I started a new post.

Comment: To do a perfect raw subtract, you need to have (originally) sample-identical tracks - any lossy data compression, aliasing, dithering, or any other distortion, and it will need further processing in something like RX, as Tetsujin said. Also, make sure they really are opposite phase and at exactly the same level. I'd love to know if it works, btw. I have a feeling you'll have problems - it's rarely straight forward. Maybe let us know in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13350/the-echo-chamber)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solutions are pretty much the same as they were a decade ago, but the AI component has improved a lot. If you don't have room ambience to contend with, this should be relatively easier.

If your two music files are identical then you can phase-reverse one against the other. What remains is the non-identical… the voiceover.

The AI component in Izoptope RX [now up to version 10] could be used to try isolate it. It can understand what is 'a voice' so knows what to try remove to isolate it.

Both will require quite a bit of trial & error, I would imagine.